# my Plist not updating or I can't find where to look

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an existing PList in my project called "Account.plist" ... it loads my initial Tableview ... and it sends said data to the detail view. I created another detail view called AddViewcontroller ... I have 5 blank text fields ... I created a button and the button action executes this code below: but I cannot find either an update to my "Account.plist" or where a new copy of my "Accounts.plist" in my Library folder for the project. any assistance would be appreciated. thank you in advance.

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [array addObject:AcctName.text];
    [array addObject:AcctNum.text];
    [array addObject:DayDue.text];
    [array addObject:paymnt.text];
    [array addObject:remBalance.text];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.plist"];

    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: true];
```

Comment: The new file is saved to the app documents folder? How are you looking for it?

Comment: writeToFile returns a Boolean of success/fail of method. double check the output

Comment: what is the Boolean method or how do I write it

Comment: originally I created the "Account.plist" in my project, I checked in the documents folder for the application and it did exist, so I copied it there...but it is not updating. I am going to add some nslogs to see if it hitting all lines of code. thank you for your responses. I appreciate it.

Comment: NSLog(@"Did write to file: %d", [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: true]);

Comment: Are you saying you copied the account file from your app bundle location which is not writable to document folder(writable location).

Comment: I copied it from my project to Library/application/documents